# Run WinPatrol AND Microsoft Security Essentials?

Tags: windows-7, 32-bit, ms-security-essentials

Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit

Can I use WinPatrol in conjunction with Microsoft Security Essentials or will there be a conflict of interest and subsequent problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Windows 7 32-bit machine with WinPatrol (Free version) and the newest version of Microsoft Security Essentials installed.  Been running the two side-by-side with no problems whatsoever for at least a year.

Answer (score 0):

After further deliberation i have decided it is better not to use winpatrol with MSSE especially as MS have put out a new version of MSSE recently